# Breeze item's arent loaded right with virtual properties on the domain class

Tags: breeze

I have on my domain class a virtual ICollection property. If i leave that property, the items that are generated by breeze after a query don't have the entityaspect attribut. If i delete the virtual, everything works.

Example:

This is A Products Poco :

```
public class Product : BaseEntity  
{


    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }       

    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

      //  if i leave the property like this, everything works fine.

    public  ICollection<Category> Categories { get; set; }

     //if i do something like this, the entities are loaded by breeze, 
       but they  got  no  entity aspect property 

    public virtual  ICollection<Category> Categories { get; set; }



}
```

Comment: My navigation properties are almost always virtual and I don't have this problem. You'll have to elaborate

Comment: Hey, sorry, i didnt see your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you disabled proxy creation and disabled lazy loading in the `DbContext`.  You can either do something like this:

```
   this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
   this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
```

Or you can use `EFContextProvider` to access the `DbContext` like this:

```
 var contextProvider = new EFContextProvider<MyDbContext>();

 contextProvider.Context //this is the DbContext
```

Comment: OK, I will have to try this out next time I use breeze. I will mark it as right anwser. Thanks for input :)